# Parsing java list of factors with insertions

Tags: java, math

**Insanely Long But necessary Intro:**
Right now, I'm writing a synthetic division calculator.  To do this, there are a few steps (for a computer to do it). 
**I have done step one**

1. The input must be (let's say `3x^2+2x^1+3x^0`) parsed into fragments of each term (like `3x^2`,`2x^1`,etc.)
2. Next, each factor must be added to an array or an array list with the degree elements.  If you are familiar with synthetic division, you know that the factors must be in order of the degree they are matched up with (`3x^2 + 2x^1 + 0x^1` must go in as `3,2,0`).  In addition, if a certain degree is missing, the number zero should be added in place.  For example, if the input is `3x^2 + 2x^0`, a zero must be added in the middle because the term with degree 1 is missing.  The output would be `3,0,2`.

What I have done to solve this problem:

If I haven't already said this, I'm writing in Java. (Please note: I'm trying to create an MVC for here.  Too see the full code, go [here](https://github.com/rselwyn/polynomial-division/blob/master/src/Polynomial.java))

```
//Cycle through all the degrees
for (int i = this.degree; i>=0; i--){
        //We can set a boolean value on 
        //whether we have found the term in the array with the correct degree
        boolean found = false;

        // arr is the array with all the terms (2x^2) etc.
        for (String each : arr){
            //checks if the current term is of the degree we are looking for (i)
            if(lookForTheTerm(each,i)){
                try{
                //Add it to the resulting array list
                coefficients.add(getCoeffFromString(arr[i]));
                }
                catch (Exception e){

                }
                //We found it 
                found = true;
                //Break out of the loop (if we found it, we don't need to keep looking)
                break;
            }           

        }
        //If we didn't find it, add a 0 to the array list
        if(!found){
            coefficients.add((float) 0);
        }

    }
    //Not shown:  After iterating, reverse the list to be correct
```

**The Issue:**

This code works if all the terms **are there**.  Meaning `3x^2+1x^1+0x^0` (there is a term of degree 2,1, and 0).

If they are out of order, it does something completely insane.

If one is missing and they are in order, it puts in the zeros, but disregards the leading term.

What is wrong with the code?  I'm almost positive that it is a semantic error.  Once again, I attempted to provide an MVC.   But if it is not enough, the full code can be seen [here.](https://github.com/rselwyn/polynomial-division/blob/master/src/Polynomial.java)

**Thanks for the help in advanced**

Comment: You have a lot of text processing using split().  Did you try debugging the terms getting put into the array?

Comment: Yes, the terms are all split correctly. @JohnScattergood

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem 1: ordering

You are parsing the degree from the first term and then using the degree to loop through the terms.  If you put 2nd degree first then it will only process 2 terms.

You could fix this by sorting your terms by degree first.

Problem 2: fewer terms

This is caused by a related problem with the degree , but worse :

```
coefficients.add(getCoeffFromString(arr[i]));
            }
            catch (Exception e){

            }
```

You are eating the exception.  If you have 2 terms, but one has 3rd degree, then dereferencing the list at index i is going to throw an out of bounds exception.